# How to get two column float left div layout to word wrap?

Tags: html, css, css-float

My HTML looks like this:

```
<body>
  <div class="nav"><ul>...</ul></div>
  <div class="view">this text won't wrap if I resize browser</div>
</body>
```

and my CSS looks like this:

```
.nav {
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-right:46px;
}

.nav a {
    font-weight:normal;
}

.nav ul {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    text-align:right;
}

.nav ul li {
    margin-bottom:7px;
}

.view {
    float:left;
}
```

If I resize the browser to be skinnier, then it won't word wrap the text in the view div at all. It will just un-float the view div and put it below the nav div.

How can I make the text in the view div word wrap instead of un-float to under the nav div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want your `.nav` div to be 200 pixels wide and I assume you want 46 pixels between the `.nav` div and the `.view` div, at least that's what I understand from the `margin-right:46px` on the `.nav` div. You don't need to float the `.view` div. In fact, you can't because if it's floated, the only way to get it next to the `.nav` div is to set a width (otherwise it will default to 100% of it's parent). But you can't set the width because you want it to grow and shrink with the size of the browser.

So floating is not an option but also not necessary. The `.nav` div is floated and because of this the `.view` div will appear underneath the `.nav` div (because floated div's are taken out of the flow). To make the `.view` div appear next to the `.nav` div you simply set a `margin-left` of 246 pixels (200px width of `.nav` + 46px margin).

```
.nav {
    width:200px;
    float:left;
}

.view {
    margin-left:246px;
}
```

Comment: Very nice. Would have never thought to do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a width on floated elements, otherwise they will take UP TO 100% width of their containers.

also, you should [clear your float](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) containers.